# How to save HTML form data on local machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Have HTML form in that some user information is filled.want to save that information on local machine. How to do that?

Comment: Your server has no access to a clients file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML page that is displayed in the users browser is only the `Response` that the server delivered on the users `Request`.

- Users requests some webpage by accessing some URL like `http://example.com/index.php`. This request is send as `HTML GET` to the server
- The server will process this request and send send pack the HTML content as Response
- The HTML content is displayed by the users browser

HTML itself does not offer any interactivity but is just a way to describe the page content.

You could add `JavaScript` to the webpage (to the HTML output) to add some interactive like alerts or a save-as dialog, but as far as I understand your question, this is not what you are looking for.

As Stephen Muecke already pointed out, there is (of course) no way that the server that processes the HTML Request can access the clients file system.

However you could the following:

- The form data is send as `POST Request` to your server.
- Your server does not respond with HTML content but with some kind of other content like a Textfile or anthing like this, which is not displayed within the browser but offered as download. The user could than use the `Save download to...` option of his browser, to save this file locally.